# How to create docker container with custom root volume size?

Tags: docker, size, volume

I have hit a limit of 10Gb for default root volume size. For this particular container I need a larger size.

So far I've seen quite dirty hacks to override default size.

Could somebody provide me and the community with a clear example of specifying bigger volume size upon container creation? Thanks!

Comment: did you try restarting docker with something like `docker daemon --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G`

Comment: @user2915097 What is effect of this command? All existing containers will be of this size? All newly created containers will be of this size? Will setting persist for my created containers after server reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to offer an alternative suggestion - don't. Stop and ask yourself why you need a larger root volume. I would suggest it's *likely* to be because you're doing something that can be done a better way.

I would suggest that instead - you use a storage container (if another 10G would be sufficient) or use a passthrough mount to a local disk.

The problem with big containers is they're somewhat at odds with what containerisation is trying to accomplish - compact, lightweight and self contained program instances.

So I would suggest instead:

docker create -v /path/to/storage:/container_mount --name storage_for_my_app  /bin/true

(Or you can just `-v /container_mount` to keep the data within the container)

Then when you fire up your container:

```
docker run -d --volumes-from storage_for_my_app your_image
```

However it may be useful to note - as of Docker 1.9, the size limit is 100G instead: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the right answer. Well, insofar as there are "right" answers with Docker.

Comment: A really useful note here is that I can always map to host system folder and not care about size. My exact case was container used /tmp folder for many files that accidentally may take more than 10G. Mounting /tmp to host folder looks logically as an overkill.